# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with gulp babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, gulp-babel

I have my react component and right now when I startup the server via gulp, it throws this error...

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: /Users/Maude/Projects/NoteTaker/src/scripts/components/notes.jsx: Unexpected token (12:6)
  10 | 
  11 |     return (
> 12 |       <div>
     |       ^
  13 |         <p>hi</p>
  14 |       </div>
  15 |     );
```

This is what the component looks like:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Notes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>hi hellooo</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Notes />, document.getElementById('notes'))
```

I'm assuming it has to do with something regarding babel in my gulpfile.js , I'm just unsure of what it is. Everything else works fine... But rendering components gets weird...

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const path = require('path');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const connect = require('gulp-connect');


// Styles
gulp.task('sass', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});


gulp.task('babel', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/components/**/*.jsx')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});


gulp.task('webserver', () => {
  connect.server({
    livereload: true
  });
});


gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('src/styles/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('src/scripts/components/*.jsx', ['babel']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'babel', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mmh, I guess this is not the perfect duplicate since you are using gulp. But it's exactly the same issue.

Comment: @FelixKling I appreciate you keeping the community at its freshest, but I think a duplicate in regards to gulp was needed. :)

Comment: @FelixKling The duplicate question is for webpack. I read all the answers but still I do not know how to configure it in gulp. Please remove the duplicate so someone can answer it clearly here.